# kubernetes time-out after re-installation on macOS

Tags: kubernetes

I followed the instructions on  https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/ on my Mac and installed Kubernetes CLI using brew.

```
brew install kubernetes-cli
```

kubectl and  Minikube were installed already some time ago, so I was expecting an update. Now kubectl version and kubernetes cluster-info time out.

```
pa-demo jps$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.2", GitCommit:"bb9ffb1654d4a729bb4cec18ff088eacc153c239", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-08-08T16:31:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.99.100:8443: i/o timeout
```

When  I try to install kubernetes-cli again, I get:

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 2 taps (homebrew/core, homebrew/cask).
==> New Formulae
topgrade
==> Updated Formulae
bison ✔            azure-cli          bwfmetaedit        erlang@20          ghostscript        jfrog-cli-go       ldc                p11-kit            smlnj              youtube-dl
sphinx-doc ✔       babel              crystal            fauna-shell        helmfile           juju               mkvtoolnix         pyside             tarsnap-gui
alexjs             bat                doctl              fortio             influxdb           kore               nginx              re2c               thors-serializer

Warning: kubernetes-cli 1.11.2 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 1.11.2, run `brew reinstall kubernetes-cli`
```

Comment: You need to be more specific when you say you "installed Kubernetes using brew". What exactly did you install? Minikube? Looks like a standard error that occurs when kubectl can't connect to a cluster.

Comment: @GrantDavidBachman I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have installed Minikube, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's actively running. You'd need to run `minikube start` to actually start the cluster on your machine. This also configures your kubeconfig file to point at the cluster it built.

Comment: interesting, I didn't expect to validate the CLI installation by connecting to Minikube as the new cluster will run in the cloud.